# Grouping a series of XML nodes based on their parent nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing a script that will eventually clean up an XML file used by a user access provisioning system at work, based on what items are parsed in to be removed.
The XML document has a various levels of child/parent nodes as below:

```
<Enterprise>
<Channel name="a">
 <busunit name="one">
  <dept name="x">
   <role name ="role1">
   <role name="role2">
  </dept>
  <dept name="y">
  <dept name="z">
 </busunit >
 <busunit name="two">
 <busunit name="three">     
</Channel>
<Channel name="b" >
<Channel name="c">
</Enterprise>
```

What I'm wanting to do is read the document and group items based on their parents, but I'm struggling to come up with a solid way of doing this because of the various node levels.

I've made a start at using a series of lists for each channel that stores a list of business units, that stores a list of departments that finally stores a list of roles (essentially a multi-dimensional list) but I'm thinking this could get terribly hard to follow quite quickly and a nightmare to debug.

A few other things to note:

- There is no set number of busunits in a channel, nor is there a set number of depts in a busunit OR a set number of roles in depts
- There are duplicate names of busunits/depts/roles across channels/busunits/departments (which is why this needs cleaning up)

Hopefully this isn't to vague to understand but what I'm wanting to know in a nutshell is:
What other alternatives do I have at my disposal other than multi-dimensional lists to group+store multiple parent/child nodes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting data into a datatable which will make it easier to delete

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Channel", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("busunit", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("dept", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("role", typeof(string));

            foreach (XElement channel in doc.Descendants("Channel"))
            {
                string channelName = (string)channel.Attribute("name");
                List<XElement> busunits = channel.Elements("busunit").ToList();
                if (busunits.Count == 0)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { channelName });
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (XElement busunit in busunits)
                    {
                        string busunitName = (string)busunit.Attribute("name");
                        List<XElement> depts = busunit.Elements("dept").ToList();
                        if (depts.Count == 0)
                        {
                            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { channelName, busunitName });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (XElement dept in depts)
                            {
                                string deptName = (string)dept.Attribute("name");
                                List<XElement> roles = dept.Elements("role").ToList();
                                if (roles.Count == 0)
                                {
                                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { channelName, busunitName, deptName });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    foreach (XElement role in roles)
                                    {
                                        string roleName = (string)role.Attribute("name");
                                        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { channelName, busunitName, deptName, roleName });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(m => m.Field<string>("Channel"))
                .ThenBy(n => n.Field<string>("busunit"))
                .ThenBy(o => o.Field<string>("dept"))
                .ThenBy(p => p.Field<string>("role"))
                .CopyToDataTable();

            //remove duplicates
            for (int row = dt.Rows.Count - 2; row >= 0; row--)
            {
                if ((dt.Rows[row].Field<object>("Channel") == dt.Rows[row + 1].Field<object>("Channel")) &&
                   (dt.Rows[row].Field<object>("busunit") == dt.Rows[row + 1].Field<object>("busunit")) &&
                   (dt.Rows[row].Field<object>("dept") == dt.Rows[row + 1].Field<object>("dept")) &&
                   (dt.Rows[row].Field<object>("role") == dt.Rows[row + 1].Field<object>("role")))
                {
                    dt.Rows[row + 1].Delete();
                }
             }
            dt.AcceptChanges();

        }
    }
}
```